# Laravel 5.2 : Route [WelcomeController.destroy] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

In my route :

`Route::resource('welcome', 'WelcomeController');`

View :

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' =>['WelcomeController.destroy', $task->id]]) }}
{{ Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And `WelcomeController` Controller :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
  $task = Task::findOrFail($id);
  $task->delete();
  return back();
}
```

The error Comes up :

`Route [WelcomeController.destroy] not defined. (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/NewTask/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `welcome.destroy` instead of `WelcomeController.destroy` in your view.

In order to verify names of routes, you can always run:

`php artisan route:list` and you will see names of all routes in your Laravel application